# ReactJS: mask input

Tags: jquery, reactjs, maskedinput

I am trying to create an masked input component using ReactJS.  Following [Mask card number input in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30671302/mask-card-number-input-in-react) i get error:  Object doesn't support property or method 'mask'.

I did have to make some changes because it seems the post may be a bit outdated, so maybe there are other things i need to change that i'm not aware of.

This is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import $ from 'jquery';

export default class MaskedInput extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props); 
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let $input_elem = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.maskedInput))[0];
        console.log($input_elem);
//      // now you have a jquery object
        $input_elem.mask("0000 0000 0000 0000");
    }

    render() {
        return <input ref={(input)=> {this.maskedInput = input; }} id="cardInput" onChange={this.props.handleChange} type="number" value="" />
    }
}
```

So, i guess i was missing the jquery-mask-plugin, which i installed with

```
npm install --save jquery-mask-plugin
```

So I changed this line:

```
import $ from 'jquery-mask-plugin';
```

But, now i get an error on this line:

```
let $input_elem = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.maskedInput))[0];
```

error:  **Function expected**

I tried removing the index at the end, but that didn't help.

Comment: seems you have a problem in `componentDidMount` here: `$input_elem.input mask("0000 0000 0000 0000");`  There's a space between `input` and `mask`

Comment: Thanks Mike Driver.  My initial post had a typo.  I just fixed it.  I still get the same error i mentioned

Comment: Try `let $input_elem = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.maskedInput));` without the `[0]`

Comment: IF that doesn't work then you need to make sure you're actually loading the jquery mask plugin from your link.

Comment: never use jquery with react, better try https://github.com/insin/react-maskedinput

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to create my own component to avoid installing third-party libraries, but since i would have to install jquery for this solution, might as well install [react-maskedinput](https://github.com/insin/react-maskedinput) which already solves the problem and it is a better choice for React than jquery.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery doesn't have `mask` method by default, so I think you have not included [this](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) plugin to code